# How to handle Pipe and escape characters while reading pipe delimited files in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I have a pipe delimited file. How to handle backslash and pipe inside the content

Here is the input

```
col1|col2|col3|col4   
123|"\|"|""|2020.01.31 12:00:30  
456|"\"|""|2020.01.31 12:00:30  
678|"|"|""|2020.01.31 12:00:30
```

I tried with below option

```
data =  spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")\
.option("inferSchema", "true")\
.option('header','true')\
.option('delimiter','|')\
.option("quote", '"')\
.option("escape","|")\
.option("escape", "\\")\
.option("timestampFormat", "yyyy.mm.dd hh:mm:ss")\
.load('s3://dummybucket/a.csv')
```

I got output as

```
col1|col2|col3|col4   
123|"\\|"|""|2020-01-31T00:00:30.000Z  
456|"\"|\""|2020-01-31T00:00:30.000Z|""  
678|"|"|""|2020-01-31T00:00:30.000Z
```

Expected output

```
col1|col2|col3|col4   
123|"\|"|""|2020-01-31T00:00:30.000Z   
456|"\"|""|2020-01-31T00:00:30.000Z    
678|"|"|""|2020-01-31T00:00:30.000Z
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared `escape` twice. However, the property can be defined only once for a dataset. You will need to define this only once.

```
.option("escape","|") \
.option("escape", "\\") \
```

- By default the value for `escape` will be `\` if not defined (link [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=dataframereader#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv)).
- You have defined your quote character as `"`. An escape character is used to escape a quote character. For example `"show this \""` would yield `show this "` if the quote character was `"` and escape was `\`.
- For this particular example, you will either need to change your `escape` to a control character such as `#` or any value which does not appear before your quote character of `"`. Hence you can't use `|` as this appears before a quote on line 1. Also you can't use `\` as that appears before quote on line 2.
- You have to specify a value for `escape` as well due to default value being `\`. This would break line 2 for you.